# Libgdx BitmapFont not displaying

Tags: libgdx

I've looked at other Stackoverflow questions and done what the answers have told me, but I can't seem to get my class to display any text.

Here's my code where all the text is being displayed:

```
package com.frinkly.jumpcat;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;

public class WorldRenderer {
    private static final float CAMERA_WIDTH = 12f;
    private static final float CAMERA_HEIGHT = 20f;

    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private float ppuX;
    private float ppuY;

    private BitmapFont font;

    private World world;
    private Cat cat;

    ShapeRenderer debugRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

    public WorldRenderer(World newWorld) {
        this.world = newWorld;
        this.cat = world.getCat();
        this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        this.cam.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2f, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2f, 0);
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/font.fnt"), false);
        font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        this.cam.update();
        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(new Matrix4().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
    }

    public void setSize(int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
        ppuX = (float) width / CAMERA_WIDTH;
        ppuY = (float) height / CAMERA_HEIGHT;
    }

    public void render() {
        cam.update();
        spriteBatch.begin();
        debugDraw();
        drawPoints();
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    private void drawPoints() {
        font.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        font.setScale(1, height/width);
        font.draw(spriteBatch, Integer.toString(cat.getPoints()), 0.5f,  height/width*0.5f);
    }

    private void debugDraw() {
        debugRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        debugRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        for(Block block : world.getBlocks()) {
            Rectangle rect1 = block.getBounds1();
            Rectangle rect2 = block.getBounds2();
            float x1 = block.getPosition().x;//+block.getPosition().x
            float y1 = block.getPosition().y;//+block.getPosition().y
            debugRenderer.setColor(new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));
            debugRenderer.rect(x1, y1, rect1.width, rect1.height);
            debugRenderer.rect(x1, y1 + rect1.height + block.getSPACE(), rect2.width, rect2.height);
        }
        Rectangle rect = cat.getBounds();
        float x1 = cat.getPosition().x + rect.x;
        float y1 = cat.getPosition().y + rect.y;
        debugRenderer.setColor(new Color(0, 1, 0, 1));
        debugRenderer.rect(x1, y1, rect.width, rect.height);
        debugRenderer.end();
    }

    private void drawBlocks() {

    }

    private void drawCat() {

    }
}
```

Here's the GameScreen that calls the renderer to display the text:

```
package com.frinkly.jumpcat;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Application.ApplicationType;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;

import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;

public class GameScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor{
    private World world;
    private WorldRenderer renderer;
    private CatController catController;
    private BlockController blockController;

    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        blockController.update(delta);
        catController.update(delta);
        renderer.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        screenWidth = width;
        screenHeight = height;
        renderer.setSize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        loadAssets();
        world = new World();
        renderer = new WorldRenderer(world);
        catController = new CatController(world);
        blockController = new BlockController(world);
        blockController.start();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    private void loadAssets() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if(keycode == Keys.SPACE) {
            catController.jumpPressed();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if(!Gdx.app.getType().equals(ApplicationType.Android)) {
            return false;
        }
        catController.jumpPressed();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if(!Gdx.app.getType().equals(ApplicationType.Android)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

My fonts are in the right folder, and I used Hiero to generate the files. I used 150 size and it generated font1png-font5.png, which I've also put in my font folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error should be in your `render()` method:

```
cam.update();
spriteBatch.begin();
debugDraw();
drawPoints();
spriteBatch.end();
```

Inside `debugDraw()` you `begin()` a `ShapeRenderer`. So 2 objects try to draw at the same time. Do the `debugDraw()` first and `begin()` your `SpriteBatch` after that:

```
cam.update();
debugDraw();
spriteBatch.begin();
drawPoints();
spriteBatch.end();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No problem. Just remember that you should never put a begin() of some renderer/batch (ModelBatch, SpriteBatch etc.) inside a begin()-end() block. Also try to keep end() calls to a minimum, as they flush the drawn things to the GPU, as much as i know, and it is a relatively slow process. So if possible use 1 batch/renderer only, else draw all things of one render/batchtype first, then the others.